# How can I alternately train two models in keras with different optimizers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have two models that draw their input values from the same training dataset. I am trying to train the two models alternately with two optimizers that have different learning rates. Hence, while training one model, I have to freeze the weights of the other model and vice versa. However, the approach that I am using is taking too long to train and even gives an OOM error. However, when I simply train the models together, no such problem occurs.

The code snippet and the image of a sample model are attached below. However, the actual models have numerous layers and high dimensional input.

[image]

```
def convA(x):
  conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu', name = 'conv21')(x)
  conv2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid',activation='relu', name = 'conv22')(conv1)
  return conv2

def convB(x):
 conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu', name = 'conv2a')(x)                                             
 conv2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid',activation='relu', name = 'conv2b')(conv1)
 return conv2  

x = Input(shape=(11,11,32), name='input1')
convP = convA(x)
convQ = convB(x)

model1 = Model(x,convP)
model2 = Model(x,convQ)

multiply_layer = keras.layers.Multiply()([model1(x), model2(x)])
conv1_reshape = keras.layers.Reshape([7*7*16],name = 'fc_reshape')(multiply_layer)
fc = keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='softmax', name = 'fc1')(conv1_reshape)

model_main = Model(x,fc)

optim1 = keras.optimizers.SGD(0.0009, momentum=0.01, nesterov=True)
optim2 = keras.optimizers.SGD(0.00009, momentum=0.01, nesterov=True)

for epoch in range(250):
  for batch in range(100):
    x_batch = x_train[batch*16:(batch+1)*16,:,:,:]
    y_batch = y_train[batch*16:(batch+1)*16,:]

    model1.trainable = False
    model2.trainable = True
    model_main.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim1, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model_main.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)

    model1.trainable = True
    model2.trainable = False
    model_main.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim2, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model_main.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)
```